# Issue passing variable to include_task file having add_host in Ansible

Tags: ansible, parameter-passing, nested-loops, scoping

I am dealing with nested loops inorder to build dynamic host using add_host.

```
Outer Loop:      with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"  // gets me the list of users
Inner Loop:      with_items: "{{ dest_ip.split(',') }}"          // gets me the list of IP addresses seperated by comma (,)
```

The below playbook works fine.

```
   - name: Add hosts
     include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gethosts.yml"
     vars:
       dest_ip: "{{ item.split('\t')[0] }}"
       file_dets: "{{ item.split('\t')[1] }}"
       USER_pass: "anystring"
#       USER_pass:  "{% if item.split('\t')[3] == 'FrontEnd' %}user1{% elif item.split('\t')[3] == 'BackEnd' %}user2{% else %}{% endif %}"
       ansible_host: localhost
       install_dir_pass: "anystring"
#       install_dir_pass: "{{ item.split('\t')[2] }}"

     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Below is my include_task gethost.yml file:

```
---
 - name: Generate JSON data
    add_host:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      groups: dest_nodes
      ansible_user: "{{ USER_pass }}"
      install_dir: "{{ install_dir_pass }}"
    with_items: "{{ dest_ip.split(',') }}"
```

I get the below error if I uncomment either USER_pass or install_dir_pass and comment the existing value:

> TASK [Generate JSON data]
>   *********************************************************************************************************************************** task path: /app/deployment/gethosts.yml:2  [WARNING]: The loop
>   variable 'item' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value
>   in the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to avoid
>   variable collisions and unexpected behavior.
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
>       "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 2\n\nThe error appears to be
>   in '/app/deployment/gethosts.yml': line 2, column 4, but may\nbe
>   elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe
>   offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n - name: Generate JSON data\n
>   ^ here\n" }
>
> NO MORE HOSTS LEFT
>
> ---
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=12   changed=1    unreachable=0
>   failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Requesting a solution to this issue and an explanation of a few questions I have.

1. The dest_ip is read and works fine with .split(,) method inside of include_task get_hosts.yml file when other variables like install_dir_pass dont seem to work.
2. When USER_pass and install_dir_pass are given simple string "AnyString" it works and is read fine inside of get_hosts.yml where as if they are assigned values using   item.split('\t')[] the playbook errors as above.

I have already tested using debug that all the entries in command_result are good and the values should be populated correctly as below.

```
   - debug:
          msg: "{{  item.split('\t')[0]  }}"
         # msg: "{{  item.split('\t')[1]  }}"
          #msg: "{{  item.split('\t')[2]  }}"
       #   msg: "{{  item.split('\t')[3]  }}"
     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is very well explained in your error message:

- There is a name collision between the `item` of each nested loops.
- You have to set the `loop_var` name in the [`loop_control`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops) option to resolve the conflict in either of the loops.

I suggest you do this on the `include_task` so that it solves the problem for any other loop inside your included file. As I have no idea what your `command_result.stdout_lines` contains exactly, I used in the below example the var name `my_result` that you should change with something fitting your situation. Note that this var will be available directly in the included file if necessary.

```
   - name: Add hosts
     include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gethosts.yml"
     vars:
       dest_ip: "{{ my_result.split('\t')[0] }}"
       file_dets: "{{ my_result.split('\t')[1] }}"
       USER_pass:  "{% if my_result.split('\t')[3] == 'FrontEnd' %}user1{% elif my_result.split('\t')[3] == 'BackEnd' %}user2{% else %}{% endif %}"
       ansible_host: localhost
       install_dir_pass: "{{ my_result.split('\t')[2] }}"
     with_items: "{{ command_result.stdout_lines }}"
     loop_control:
       loop_var: my_result
```